# Using fixtures in django.test.TestCase

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-tests

I try to use fixtures in django.test.TestCase. It works correctly, but I do it for the first time. What is the best practice in this case?

```
from django.test import Client, TestCase
    
class SomeTestClass(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['fixtures.json',]

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        cls.user = User.objects.get(id=1) # from fixtures
        cls.authorized_client = Client()
        cls.authorized_client.force_login(cls.user)
        cls.someobject = Someclass.objects.get(id=1) # from fixtures
        cls.anotherobject = Anotherclass.objects.get(id=1) # from fixtures

    def test(self):
        ...
```